# Multiple editable rows in JTable header

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable

I need to have multiple editable rows in JTable header, so that the same header column could contain both JTextField and JButton.

I have found how to implement editable header cells and how to split header cells. However it turned out that these approaches are somewhat different and I would need to fuse them into one.

Is there any multiple editable JTable header rows solutions which are already developed and so that I wouldn't need to reinvent the bicycle?

---

What I have found so far:

---

Editable Header row code taken from: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/EditableHeaderTableExample2.htm

[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
* @version 1.0 08/22/99
*/
public class EditableHeaderTableExample2 extends JFrame {

public EditableHeaderTableExample2() {
     super("EditableHeader Example");

     JTable table = new JTable(7, 5);
     TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
     table.setTableHeader(new EditableHeader(columnModel));

     String[] items = { "Dog", "Cat" };
     JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
     for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       combo.addItem(items[i]);
     }
     ComboRenderer renderer = new ComboRenderer(items);

     EditableHeaderTableColumn col;
     // column 1
     col = (EditableHeaderTableColumn) table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
     col.setHeaderValue(combo.getItemAt(0));
     col.setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
     col.setHeaderEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));

     // column 3
     col = (EditableHeaderTableColumn) table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
     col.setHeaderValue(combo.getItemAt(0));
     //col.setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
     col.setHeaderEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));

     JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
     getContentPane().add(pane);
}

class ComboRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

     ComboRenderer(String[] items) {
       for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         addItem(items[i]);
       }
     }

     public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
         Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
         int column) {
       setSelectedItem(value);
       return this;
     }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     EditableHeaderTableExample2 frame = new EditableHeaderTableExample2();
     frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
         System.exit(0);
       }
     });
     frame.setSize(300, 100);
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class EditableHeader extends JTableHeader implements CellEditorListener {
    public final int HEADER_ROW = -10;

    transient protected int editingColumn;

    transient protected TableCellEditor cellEditor;

    transient protected Component editorComp;

    public EditableHeader(TableColumnModel columnModel) {
     super(columnModel);
     setReorderingAllowed(false);
     cellEditor = null;
     recreateTableColumn(columnModel);
    }

    public void updateUI() {
     setUI(new EditableHeaderUI());
     resizeAndRepaint();
     invalidate();
    }

    protected void recreateTableColumn(TableColumnModel columnModel) {
     int n = columnModel.getColumnCount();
     EditableHeaderTableColumn[] newCols = new EditableHeaderTableColumn[n];
     TableColumn[] oldCols = new TableColumn[n];
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       oldCols[i] = columnModel.getColumn(i);
       newCols[i] = new EditableHeaderTableColumn();
       newCols[i].copyValues(oldCols[i]);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       columnModel.removeColumn(oldCols[i]);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       columnModel.addColumn(newCols[i]);
     }
    }

    public boolean editCellAt(int index) {
     return editCellAt(index);
    }

    public boolean editCellAt(int index, EventObject e) {
     if (cellEditor != null && !cellEditor.stopCellEditing()) {
       return false;
     }
     if (!isCellEditable(index)) {
       return false;
     }
     TableCellEditor editor = getCellEditor(index);

     if (editor != null && editor.isCellEditable(e)) {
       editorComp = prepareEditor(editor, index);
       editorComp.setBounds(getHeaderRect(index));
       add(editorComp);
       editorComp.validate();
       setCellEditor(editor);
       setEditingColumn(index);
       editor.addCellEditorListener(this);

       return true;
     }
     return false;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int index) {
     if (getReorderingAllowed()) {
       return false;
     }
     int columnIndex = columnModel.getColumn(index).getModelIndex();
     EditableHeaderTableColumn col = (EditableHeaderTableColumn) columnModel
         .getColumn(columnIndex);
     return col.isHeaderEditable();
    }

    public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int index) {
     int columnIndex = columnModel.getColumn(index).getModelIndex();
     EditableHeaderTableColumn col = (EditableHeaderTableColumn) columnModel
         .getColumn(columnIndex);
     return col.getHeaderEditor();
    }

    public void setCellEditor(TableCellEditor newEditor) {
     TableCellEditor oldEditor = cellEditor;
     cellEditor = newEditor;

     // firePropertyChange

     if (oldEditor != null && oldEditor instanceof TableCellEditor) {
       ((TableCellEditor) oldEditor)
           .removeCellEditorListener((CellEditorListener) this);
     }
     if (newEditor != null && newEditor instanceof TableCellEditor) {
       ((TableCellEditor) newEditor)
           .addCellEditorListener((CellEditorListener) this);
     }
    }

    public Component prepareEditor(TableCellEditor editor, int index) {
     Object value = columnModel.getColumn(index).getHeaderValue();
     boolean isSelected = true;
     int row = HEADER_ROW;
     JTable table = getTable();
     Component comp = editor.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value,
         isSelected, row, index);
     if (comp instanceof JComponent) {
        ((JComponent) comp).setNextFocusableComponent(this);
     }
     return comp;
    }

    public TableCellEditor getCellEditor() {
     return cellEditor;
    }

    public Component getEditorComponent() {
     return editorComp;
    }

    public void setEditingColumn(int aColumn) {
     editingColumn = aColumn;
    }

    public int getEditingColumn() {
     return editingColumn;
    }

    public void removeEditor() {
     TableCellEditor editor = getCellEditor();
     if (editor != null) {
       editor.removeCellEditorListener(this);

       requestFocus();
       remove(editorComp);

       int index = getEditingColumn();
       Rectangle cellRect = getHeaderRect(index);

       setCellEditor(null);
       setEditingColumn(-1);
       editorComp = null;

       repaint(cellRect);
     }
    }

    public boolean isEditing() {
     return (cellEditor == null) ? false : true;
    }

    //
    // CellEditorListener
    //
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
     TableCellEditor editor = getCellEditor();
     if (editor != null) {
       Object value = editor.getCellEditorValue();
       int index = getEditingColumn();
       columnModel.getColumn(index).setHeaderValue(value);
       removeEditor();
     }
    }

    public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
     removeEditor();
    }

    //
    // public void setReorderingAllowed(boolean b) {
    //   reorderingAllowed = false;
    // }    
}

class EditableHeaderUI extends BasicTableHeaderUI {

    protected MouseInputListener createMouseInputListener() {
     return new MouseInputHandler((EditableHeader) header);
    }

    public class MouseInputHandler extends BasicTableHeaderUI.MouseInputHandler {
         private Component dispatchComponent;

         protected EditableHeader header;

         public MouseInputHandler(EditableHeader header) {
           this.header = header;
         }

         private void setDispatchComponent(MouseEvent e) {
           Component editorComponent = header.getEditorComponent();
           Point p = e.getPoint();
           Point p2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(header, p, editorComponent);
           dispatchComponent = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(
               editorComponent, p2.x, p2.y);
         }

         private boolean repostEvent(MouseEvent e) {
           if (dispatchComponent == null) {
             return false;
           }
           MouseEvent e2 = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(header, e,
               dispatchComponent);
           dispatchComponent.dispatchEvent(e2);
           return true;
         }

         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           if (!SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
             return;
           }
           super.mousePressed(e);

           if (header.getResizingColumn() == null) {
             Point p = e.getPoint();
             TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
             int index = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(p.x);
             if (index != -1) {
               if (header.editCellAt(index, e)) {
                 setDispatchComponent(e);
                 repostEvent(e);
               }
             }
           }
         }

         public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
           super.mouseReleased(e);
           if (!SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
             return;
           }
           repostEvent(e);
           dispatchComponent = null;
         }

    }   

}

class EditableHeaderTableColumn extends TableColumn {

    protected TableCellEditor headerEditor;

    protected boolean isHeaderEditable;

    public EditableHeaderTableColumn() {
     setHeaderEditor(createDefaultHeaderEditor());
     isHeaderEditable = true;
    }

    public void setHeaderEditor(TableCellEditor headerEditor) {
     this.headerEditor = headerEditor;
    }

    public TableCellEditor getHeaderEditor() {
     return headerEditor;
    }

    public void setHeaderEditable(boolean isEditable) {
     isHeaderEditable = isEditable;
    }

    public boolean isHeaderEditable() {
     return isHeaderEditable;
    }

    public void copyValues(TableColumn base) {
     modelIndex = base.getModelIndex();
     identifier = base.getIdentifier();
     width = base.getWidth();
     minWidth = base.getMinWidth();
     setPreferredWidth(base.getPreferredWidth());
     maxWidth = base.getMaxWidth();
     headerRenderer = base.getHeaderRenderer();
     headerValue = base.getHeaderValue();
     cellRenderer = base.getCellRenderer();
     cellEditor = base.getCellEditor();
     isResizable = base.getResizable();
    }

    protected TableCellEditor createDefaultHeaderEditor() {
     return new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField());
    }

}
```

---

Multiple rows in the same JTable header column code (Fixed for java 7)
taken from:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GroupableGroupHeaderExample.htm

[image]

Code:
Column group class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;


/**
 * ColumnGroup
 *
 * @version 1.0 10/20/98
 * @author Nobuo Tamemasa
 */

class ColumnGroup {
  protected TableCellRenderer renderer;
  protected Vector v;
  protected String text;
  protected int margin=0;

  public ColumnGroup(String text) {
    this(null,text);
  }

  public ColumnGroup(TableCellRenderer renderer,String text) {
    if (renderer == null) {
      this.renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
             JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
              if (header != null) {
                  setForeground(header.getForeground());
                  setBackground(header.getBackground());
                  setFont(header.getFont());
              }
              setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
              setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
              setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
              return this;
          }
      };
    } else {
      this.renderer = renderer;
    }
    this.text = text;
    v = new Vector();
  }


  /**
   * @param obj    TableColumn or ColumnGroup
   */
  public void add(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) { return; }
    v.addElement(obj);
    /*if(obj instanceof JTextField) {
        this.setHeaderRenderer(renderer)
    }*/
  }


  /**
   * @param c    TableColumn
   * @param v    ColumnGroups
   */
  public Vector getColumnGroups(TableColumn c, Vector g) {
    g.addElement(this);
    if (v.contains(c)) return g;    
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
        Vector groups = 
          (Vector)((ColumnGroup)obj).getColumnGroups(c,(Vector)g.clone());
        if (groups != null) return groups;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public TableCellRenderer getHeaderRenderer() {
    return renderer;
  }

  public void setHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer) {
    if (renderer != null) {
       this.renderer = renderer;
    }
  }

  public Object getHeaderValue() {
    return text;
  }

  public Dimension getSize(JTable table) {
    Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        table, getHeaderValue(), false, false,-1, -1);
    int height = comp.getPreferredSize().height; 
    int width  = 0;
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof TableColumn) {
        TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)obj;
        width += aColumn.getWidth();
        //width += margin;
      } else {
        width += ((ColumnGroup)obj).getSize(table).width;
      }
    }
    return new Dimension(width, height);
  }

  public void setColumnMargin(int margin) {
    this.margin = margin;
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
         ((ColumnGroup)obj).setColumnMargin(margin);
       }
    }
  }
```

GroupableHeaderExample

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/**
 * @version 1.0 11/09/98
 */
public class GroupableHeaderExample extends JFrame {

  GroupableHeaderExample() {
    super( "Groupable Header Example" );

    String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };
    JComboBox petList = new JComboBox(petStrings);

    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]{
      {"foo","ja"},
      {"bar","en"}},
    new Object[]{new JTextField(), petList});//"Input box","Combo Box"});

    JTable table = new JTable( dm ) {
      protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
          return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
      }
    };


    TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
    ColumnGroup g_name = new ColumnGroup("Title1");
    g_name.add(cm.getColumn(0));
    //g_name.add(cm.getColumn(1));
    ColumnGroup g_lang = new ColumnGroup("Title2");
    g_lang.add(cm.getColumn(1));
    /*ColumnGroup g_other = new ColumnGroup("Others");
    g_other.add(cm.getColumn(4));
    g_other.add(cm.getColumn(5));
    g_lang.add(g_other);*/

    GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader)table.getTableHeader();
    header.addColumnGroup(g_name);
    header.addColumnGroup(g_lang);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );
    getContentPane().add( scroll );
    setSize( 400, 120 );   
  }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    GroupableHeaderExample frame = new GroupableHeaderExample();
    frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
  System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

GroupableTableHeader class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/**
  * GroupableTableHeader
  *
  * @version 1.0 10/20/98
  * @author Nobuo Tamemasa
  */

public class GroupableTableHeader extends JTableHeader {
  private static final String uiClassID = "GroupableTableHeaderUI";
  protected Vector columnGroups = null;

  public GroupableTableHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
    super(model);
    setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
    setReorderingAllowed(false);
  }
  public void updateUI(){
   setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
  }

  public void setReorderingAllowed(boolean b) {
    reorderingAllowed = false;
  }

  public void addColumnGroup(ColumnGroup g) {
    if (columnGroups == null) {
      columnGroups = new Vector();
    }
    columnGroups.addElement(g);
  }

  public Enumeration getColumnGroups(TableColumn col) {
    if (columnGroups == null) return null;
    Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
      Vector v_ret = (Vector)cGroup.getColumnGroups(col,new Vector());
      if (v_ret != null) { 
  return v_ret.elements();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void setColumnMargin() {
    if (columnGroups == null) return;
    int columnMargin = getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
    Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
      cGroup.setColumnMargin(columnMargin);
    }
  }

}
```

GroupableTableHeaderUI class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class GroupableTableHeaderUI extends BasicTableHeaderUI {

  public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
    if (header.getColumnModel() == null) return;
    ((GroupableTableHeader)header).setColumnMargin();
    int column = 0;
    Dimension size = header.getSize();
    Rectangle cellRect  = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    int columnMargin = header.getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();

    Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      cellRect.height = size.height;
      cellRect.y      = 0;
      TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)enumeration.nextElement();
      Enumeration cGroups = ((GroupableTableHeader)header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);
      if (cGroups != null) {
        int groupHeight = 0;
        while (cGroups.hasMoreElements()) {
          ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)cGroups.nextElement();
          Rectangle groupRect = (Rectangle)h.get(cGroup);
          if (groupRect == null) {
            groupRect = new Rectangle(cellRect);
            Dimension d = cGroup.getSize(header.getTable());
            groupRect.width  = d.width;
            groupRect.height = d.height;    
            h.put(cGroup, groupRect);
          }
          paintCell(g, groupRect, cGroup);
          groupHeight += groupRect.height;
          cellRect.height = size.height - groupHeight;
          cellRect.y      = groupHeight;
        }
      }      
      cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth();// + columnMargin;
      if (cellRect.intersects(clipBounds)) {
        paintCell(g, cellRect, column);
      }
      cellRect.x += cellRect.width;
      column++;
    }
  }

  private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int columnIndex) {
    TableColumn aColumn = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
    TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
    //revised by Java2s.com
    renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
          JLabel header = new JLabel();
            header.setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
            header.setBackground(table.getTableHeader().getBackground());
            header.setFont(table.getTableHeader().getFont());

          header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          header.setText(value.toString());
          header.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
            return header;
        }

    };
    Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(),false, false, -1, columnIndex);

        c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));

    rendererPane.add(c);
    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, c, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
        cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
  }

  private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect,ColumnGroup cGroup) {
    TableCellRenderer renderer = cGroup.getHeaderRenderer();
      //revised by Java2s.com
     // if(renderer == null){
//      return ;
  //    }

    Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
      header.getTable(), cGroup.getHeaderValue(),false, false, -1, -1);
    rendererPane.add(component);
    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, component, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
        cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
  }

  private int getHeaderHeight() {
    int height = 0;
    TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
    for(int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
      TableColumn aColumn = columnModel.getColumn(column);
      TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
      //revised by Java2s.com
      if(renderer == null){
      return 40;
      }

      Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false, false,-1, column);
      int cHeight = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
      Enumeration e = ((GroupableTableHeader)header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);      
      if (e != null) {
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
          ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
          cHeight += cGroup.getSize(header.getTable()).height;
        }
      }
      height = Math.max(height, cHeight);
    }
    return height;
  }

  private Dimension createHeaderSize(long width) {
    TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
    width += columnModel.getColumnMargin() * columnModel.getColumnCount();
    if (width > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
      width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return new Dimension((int)width, getHeaderHeight());
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
    long width = 0;
    Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)enumeration.nextElement();
      width = width + aColumn.getPreferredWidth();
    }
    return createHeaderSize(width);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why do you need editable multi header? 2) Seems you need implement editor/renderer by yourself as in first example for each column or column group.

Comment: 1) First row of the column is for name and the button, which could perform table sorting, second row is for JTextField, which is used for table filtering purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- just idea to use TableCellEditor in JTableHeader is wrong, nor multi_line_header, to buy Jide (support)
- simpler as is possible to use RowFilter from JTextField,
- note don't forget to [convert indexes from view coordinates to model coordinates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

[image]

.

[image]

.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

//code based on posts by @camickr     

public class TableFilterRow implements TableColumnModelListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JTable table = new JTable(3, 5);
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    // Panel for text fields
    private JPanel filterRow = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));

    public TableFilterRow() {
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(this);
        filterRow = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            filterRow.add(new JTextField(" Sum at - " + i));
        }
        columnMarginChanged(new ChangeEvent(table.getColumnModel()));
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(filterRow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    //  Implement TableColumnModelListener methods
    //  (Note: instead of implementing a listener you should be able to
    //  override the columnMarginChanged and columMoved methods of JTable)
    @Override
    public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        int columns = tcm.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) filterRow.getComponent(i);
            Dimension d = textField.getPreferredSize();
            d.width = tcm.getColumn(i).getWidth();
            textField.setPreferredSize(d);
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                filterRow.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
        Component moved = filterRow.getComponent(e.getFromIndex());
        filterRow.remove(e.getFromIndex());
        filterRow.add(moved, e.getToIndex());
        filterRow.validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableFilterRow frame = new TableFilterRow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no multiple rows in the table header.

Comment: +1 nice suggestion, also i used that header without side effects

Comment: There are no multiple rows in the table header. == you can to simulating multipe rows by using decorations (simple) from JTableHeader in 1st. and 2nd. row, then JTable should be without JTableHeader

Comment: I tried this method and faced one bug, can you look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890707/tablecolumnmodellistener-jpanel-revalidate-method-ruins-swing-elements-compos