# Adding two objects in one cell on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, tablecellrenderer

I'm making a program that is some kind of a room manager,

Every day there are different clients in each room and sometimes one room have two shift in it: morning and evening.

I want to, in days that 2 clients are listed at the same room in different shifts, split the cell (which is a `JButton`) into two buttons, both contained in the same cell and to color every client in its own color.

This is a screen shot of my app:

[image: This is what I've done so far.]

And this is what I wish to accomplish:

[image]

Any ideas for how can I split the atom like that?

Comment: by Renderering JPanel with desired type of JComponents, or possible with default JLabel/JComponent (have to add LayoutManager)

Comment: that would be great, if possible. can you show me an example please ?

Comment: [simplest as is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6355910/714968), but then you have to create own [JTableHeader](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26861494/714968) (couldn't be important, up to, until RowFilter/Sorter isn't used)

Comment: You'll need a `CellEditor` for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513).

Comment: thanks all, especially @trashgod. post it as an answer , and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TableCellRenderer` can [render](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) two buttons in a panel, but you'll also need a `TableCellEditor`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513). Note in particular how each editor overrides `getCellEditorValue()`.